# How can I make my embed fields like this in discord.js v13?

Tags: discord.js

[Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvmhq.png)

Can someone explain how I can make my embeds like that in discord.js v13?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `markdown` on `embed` and some logic to create this wonderful embed.

````js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("SERVER INFO")
    .addFields(
      {name: "```Field1```", value: "```Something field1```", inline: true},
      {name: "```Field2```", value: "```Something field2```", inline: true},

   )
   .addField("```Field3```", "```Something field3```")
   .addFields(
      {name: "```Field1```", value: "```Something field1```", inline: true},
      {name: "```Field2```", value: "```Something field2```", inline: true},
   )
   .setColor('RANDOM')
   .setTimestamp()
        

message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
````

[image: Like this]

For another purpose, calling a `const` & `let` & `var`, you can use `backslash + backquote`.

```js
const user = message.author.username;
        const user1 = message.author.id;
        const user2 = message.author.tag;

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("SERVER INFO")
        .addFields(
            {name: "Field1", value: `\`\`\`${user}\`\`\``, inline: true},
            {name: "Field2", value: `\`\`\`${user1}\`\`\``, inline: true},

        )
        .addField("Field3", `\`\`\`${user2}\`\`\``)
        .addFields(
            {name: "Field4", value: `\`\`\`${user}\`\`\``, inline: true},
            {name: "Field5", value: `\`\`\`${user1}\`\`\``, inline: true},

        )
        .addField("Field6", `\`\`\`${user2}\`\`\``)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTimestamp()
        

        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```

[image: Like this]